# Capitalise first letter of every word in a string on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'd like to capitalise the first character of every word in a string. Normally in c# it would be possible using `TextInfo.ToTitleCase(string)`. Unfortunately this does not exist for windows phone. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed the TextInfo class is not present within the windows phone api.
So you'd have to implement that behavior by yourself (maybe a [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383977.aspx) or a [custom format provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?).
Anyways, here is discussed how you could do that: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/aca32898-c161-411b-bfbb-6631956aba2d/where-is-textinfototitlecase?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: For anyone else this is the code `private string toTitleCase(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return null;
    if (value.Length == 0)
        return value;

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(value);
    result[0] = char.ToUpper(result[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < result.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(result[i - 1]))
            result[i] = char.ToUpper(result[i]);
        else
            result[i] = char.ToLower(result[i]);
    }
    return result.ToString();
}`